# changing <1> to _1

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, vim, vi

I need to change something like

```
<1> to _1
<21> to _21
```

Is there a way I can automate this using sed, or awk or vi ?

Note: The number inside the angular brackets varies.

Comment: Yes that is possible, it is also possible to do that just with the shell. Is asking whether it is possible really helpful? You could have tried and found a solution in max 5 minutes of searching+reading. Then you would have known that it is possible **and** how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/<\([0-9]*\)>/_\1/g'
```

Running this on the example in the question produces

```
_1 to _1
_21 to _21
```

The pattern `<\([0-9]*\)>` matches any number of digits inside `<...>`.  The replacement text replaces this `<...>` bit of input with the digits (if there are any) prefixed by `_`.

---

In Vi:

```
:%s/<\([0-9]*\)>/_\1/g
```

This is equivalent to the `sed` solution, for obvious historical reasons.

---

If you have the string `<21>` in a shell variable `var` in Bash:

```
printf '%s\n' "_${var//[<>]/}"
```

This will print `_21` using the variable substitution `${parameter//pattern/string}`.

---

With `tr`.  Note: This gives the *appearance* of working on a very limited set of input.  It blindly replaces `<` with `_` and deletes `>`, with no regard for where they occur:

```
tr '<' '_' <file.in | tr -d '>'
```

This is more of a joke solution than anything serious, but *will work* if the only `<` and `>` that occurs in the input are the ones with digits in-between.